# Importing txt as dataframe in python

Tags: python, pandas, import

I have a txt file with the following format:

```
[(u'this guy',u'hey there',u'dfd fasd awe wedsad,daeraes',1),
 (u'that guy',u'cya',u'dfd fasd es',1),
 (u'another guy',u'hi',u'dfawe wedsad,daeraes',-1)]
```

and I would like to import it in `python` as a dataframe with 4 columns. I have tried:

```
trial = []
for line in open('filename.txt','r'):
     trial.append(line.rstrip())
```

which give each line as a text. Using:

```
import pandas as pd
pd.read_csv('filename.txt', sep=",", header = None)
```

Using read_csv from pandas and separating in comma it was also taking into consideration the comma inside the text of the variables.

```
             0               1                 2                   3        4   5
    0   [(u'this guy'   u'hey there'    u'dfd fasd awe wedsad   daeraes'    1)  NaN
    1   (u'that guy'    u'cya'           u'dfd fasd es'           1)      NaN   NaN
    2   (u'another guy' u'hi'            u'dfawe wedsad         daeraes' -1)]   NaN
```

Any idea how to overpass that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have the data in data.txt.

```
py_array = eval(open("data.txt").read())
dataframe = pd.DataFrame(py_array)
```

Python needs to parse the file first.
It doesn't make sense using `read_csv` since it isn't close enough to csv format.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you mean python, not matlab.

The data is already a matrix.

```
aa=[(u'this guy',u'hey there',u'dfd fasd awe wedsad,daeraes',1),
 (u'that guy',u'cya',u'dfd fasd es',1),
 (u'another guy',u'hi',u'dfawe wedsad,daeraes',-1)]


for i in range(3):
    for j in range(4):
        print aa[i][j]
```

output:

```
this guy
hey there
dfd fasd awe wedsad,daeraes
1
that guy
cya
dfd fasd es
1
another guy
hi
dfawe wedsad,daeraes
-1
```